# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in FavoritesController#index Couldn't find Dishing with 'id'=1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm fairly new to RoR. I'm getting an error when trying to run this command. Any thoughts on the cause?

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in FavoritesController#index
>   Couldn't find Dishing with 'id'=1

Extracted source (around line #24):

```
<td><%= Dish.find(favorite.dishing_id).dish_name %></td>
<% d = Dishing.find(favorite.dishing_id) %>
<td><%= Restaurant.find(d.restaurant_id).name %></td>
<td><%= User.find(favorite.user_id).email %></td>'
```

Error is occurring with this line of code:

```
<% d = Dishing.find(favorite.dishing_id) %>
```

Here is my **favorites_controller.rb**:

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
def index
@favorites = Favorite.all
end

def show
@favorite = Favorite.find(params[:id])
end

def new
@favorite = Favorite.new
end

def create
@favorite = Favorite.new
@favorite.dish_comment = params[:dish_comment]
@favorite.user_id = curent_user.id
d = params[:dish_id]
r = params[:restaurant_id]
# find_by

if @favorite.save
  redirect_to "/favorites", :notice => "Favorite created successfully."
else
  render 'new'
end
end

def edit
@favorite = Favorite.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@favorite = Favorite.find(params[:id])

@favorite.dish_comment = params[:dish_comment]
@favorite.dishing_id = params[:dishing_id]
@favorite.user_id = params[:user_id]

if @favorite.save
  redirect_to "/favorites", :notice => "Favorite updated successfully."
else
  render 'edit'
end
end

def destroy
@favorite = Favorite.find(params[:id])

@favorite.destroy

redirect_to "/favorites", :notice => "Favorite deleted."
end
end
```

Comment: Do you have in your DB stored `Dishing.find(1)`?

Comment: post your controller file

Comment: Probably my only comment would be how/where are the Dishing(s) being created? Ensure that you're able to create a dishing and then your issue should be resolved. Also, I'd assume you've setup your associations in your models, a possible problem could be that a dishing has been deleted but the favorite wasn't deleted with it

Comment: You seem to be using the same parameter/value (`dishing_id`) to find the `Dish` as well as `Dishing`. Might want to look there (basing this off the first 'extracted source` code block above). It's hard to imagine that `Dish.find(favorite.dishing_id`)` and `Dishing.find(favorite.dishing_id)` would work - correctly - for both queries.

Comment: @Vucko: No. It's possible that I created a sample dishing record and later deleted it.

Comment: is there a dishing for that favorite?

Comment: @oreoluwa: Dishings are a combination of Dishes and Restaurants (should have been named Menu Items). I am able to create new Dishing entries without issue, but am still getting the ActiveRecord issue.

Comment: @craig.kaminsky: Favorite is a table joining a user_id and a dishing_id. The Dishing table joins a dish_id and a restaurant_id. I'm not sure which (if either) query is correct.

Comment: @jhonquintero: Yes. Favorite is a table joining a user_id and a dishing_id. I want the user to be able to see/select a dish and a restaurant, and have the  code search for an existing dishing (combination of the two), and if it doesn't exist, create a new one, and save the dishing and user as a new favorite.

Comment: If Favorite is a joining table, I don't know if it makes sense having a FavoritesController?

Comment: @oreoluwa: I'm not sure how else I could structure it. Any thoughts?

Comment: @DharmeshRupani Posted it! Thanks!

Comment: If the project is on Github, would you mind sharing the repo here? I could help look into it. Or if the project is just starting, you could reset your db and add a constraint to your has_many models(such as dependent: :destroy).

Comment: @oreoluwa: Here's my project https://github.com/afreder0/pear_review_final/pull/1 Thanks for your insight!

Comment: branches on that repo are wrong... there is no way to checkout `pear_review` (unless i'm doing something wrong...)

Comment: @jhonquintero: What do you mean branches are wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve the root of the problem, but ended up getting rid of the error by adding a new id:1 entry into the Dishing table. I have since added a :dependent => :destroy into the Dishing model, so hopefully this won't happen again. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be assuming that you have two records with the same ID in two different tables.

That's not generally safe. Instead of adding a record to dishings with the matching ID, you should fix the architecture of your program.

A `Dish` and a `Dishing` should not have to share the same ID. Add a `dish_id` and a `dishing_id` to your Favorite.